# Why does linearizing a logarithmic plot slightly increase the $R^2$ of the line of best fit?

Tags: linear-transformations, graphing-functions

Why does linearizing a logarithmic plot slightly increase the $R^2$ of the line of best fit?
My graphs are shown below...

[Logarithmic-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqbrq.png)

[Linearized-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9r76.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $R^2$ is the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient). It quantifies linear correlation. It can be misleadingly low when the relationship between variables is nonlinear. [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) is a slight variant on the same idea, where we compute the ranks of each coordinate, then take Pearson's $R^2$ for those. An invertible order-preserving transformation of one or both variables doesn't change Spearman's coefficient, so it's equal to the Pearson coefficient you obtained from a transformation that makes the relationship linear, i.e. $0.9276$ as opposed to $0.9227$.

But the values are close together, because over sufficiently small ranges linearization is a good approximation of a more complex relationship. (This follows from calculus.) By "small range", in the case of $y$ exponential in $x$ I mean $y$ doesn't vary too much in relative terms (i.e. over too many orders of magnitude), nor $x$ too much in absolute terms.